# Android notification width

Tags: android, notifications, size, width

I am writing an [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aragaer.reminder) that builds a notification from several "symbols". Sometimes these won't fit and I'll just stop and add a number of symbols that did not fit.

Currently I'm looking at device's screen width to determine the number of symbols that do fit. Like this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
int num = dm.widthPixels / height;
```

where height is "hardcoded" value of 64dp.

This does not work on tablets though. As result I'm losing rightmost symbols. Is there any way to determine the actual amount of space in my notification?

On this picture I'm using another hardcoded value of no more than 7 symbols total.
[image]

Comment: I guess you can use GridLayout and set row number to 1 and column number to whatever you want. Gridlayout is included in support library.

Comment: I don't know how much columns I can have, that's the problem.

Comment: How many symbols you want to display?

Comment: As much as I can fit into notification without scaling down. If I can't fit all the symbols, I want to display a "list" symbol that contains number of symbols that did not fit. That's why I can't simply put all symbols into notification and expect that any overflow will be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer I've been waiting for: 478dp

[Source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/system_bar_notification_panel.xml)

Which results in about 7.5 symbols per notification and having a value of 7 hardcoded is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Are using height=64 or the equivalent of 64dp in pixels?

Why not get the width and height of your top layer to get the usable screen size instead of full screen size (including system and ActionBars)?

Comment: Equivalent of 64dp in pixels. On tablets notification area is not as wide as screen. I'd post a screenshot in a few hours.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below code:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(notification_description).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle() .bigText(msg).
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.application_icon_notification)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer doesn't answer the question at all.